# Best practice when columns missing from dataframe and adding null values in the correct column order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

We're creating several dataframes for our API responses, an example of the API response is user_fields_data, in this example I'm missing website, but with other user_fields_data responses I'm missing name, sometimes biography:

```
user_fields_data = {'followers_count': 127067, 'biography': 'Loe', 'follows_count': 596, 'media_count': 280, 'name': 'Refe', 'profile_picture_url': 'https://s9AB7F', 'username': 're', 'id': '1782'}
```

I've created the below with multiple `if` statements, but is there a cleaner way to do this keeping in mind that they have to be in the correct order column.

```
        x = pd.DataFrame(user_fields_data.items())
        x.set_index(0, inplace=True)
        user_fields_df = x.transpose()

        if 'biography' not in user_fields_df:
            user_fields_df.insert(1, "biography", 'null')

        if 'name' not in user_fields_df:
            user_fields_df.insert(4, "name", 'null')

        if 'website' not in user_fields_df:
            user_fields_df.insert(7, "website", 'null')
```

Comment: do you build only one row dataframes? or do you append this one to a larger dataframe?

Comment: @enke one row dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call your API multiple times in a row, collect responses into a Python datastructure (a list or a dict) then create your dataframe one time.

If you need to add some records while your program is running, use `pd.concat` to add new record (or `df.append`). Oviously, you have to convert your new record to a new dataframe: `pd.concat([df, new_df])`.

In the 2 cases, don't worry about missing columns, Pandas use the union of columns to build the dataframe and missing values are automatically filled by `NaN`. If this value is not what you want, you can simple use `.fillna('null')` or better `.fillna({'name': 'null', follows_count: -1})`.

**Update**

If you want to have all columns in each dataframe, create a list with your columns and use `reindex` like `df.reindex(COLS, fill_value='null', axis=1)`

Comment: I'm not appending the dataframes, in this case we're just loading each df to s3.

Comment: Can you check my update please?